# How to fix 'null' value in Image Upload in Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the download link of the image uploaded on Firebase Storage unto Cloud Firestore.

The url of the img prints successfully but in the firebase console, it's giving me a null value.

I have tried to implement this image upload severally and would appreciate some help.

```
//Setting url

String url;

//Selecting image from Image Picker

Future _getImage() async {
 var selectedImage =
 await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
 setState(() {_image = selectedImage;});
 }

//Uploading image on FireStore

Future<void> uploadPic() async {
 String filename = basename(_image.path);
 final Storage Reference refer = 
 FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profileImages').child(filename);
 final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = refer.putFile(_image);
 var downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
 final url = downloadUrl.toString();
 print(url.toString());
 return url;
 }

//Setting image: in firestore to url

Future<void> saveUser(String email, String uid) async {
 Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
  DocumentReference reference =
 Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid);
  await reference.setData({
    "email": email,
    "name": _name,
    "username": _username,
    "mobile": _mobile,
    "createdDate": DateTime.now(),
    "image": url,
      }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
     });
   });
 }

//onPressed
 uploadPic();
```

[Output showing print of downloadUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saXaN.png)
[Showing null value in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKLQ5.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: The formatting of your code is also making it difficult for me to follow.  I can't tell which curly braces match which other curly braces.

Comment: How are you passing the `url` variable to the `saveUser` function? Is it a variable set in your Widget? If so, you're not telling `uploadPic` to assign the new download url to your variable. Could you try printing the url in the `saveUser` function and see if it's null?

Comment: I apologise. Will reformat the code

Comment: @mertcanb Assigned it to the function by calling it from the extended State. It is not a variable set in the widget. Do i need to pass the url in the uploadPic() function? If i do print(url.toString()), it prints out the url. It's printing out the URL but it is not assigning it to the image:

Comment: I think u have to await until u get the url so use  - :await uploadPic();